# What am I missing here

Tags: c++, templates

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    using namespace std;

    template<class T, unsigned int ssize =100 >
    class StackTepmlate{
        T StackTepmlate[ssize];
        int top;
    public:
        StackTepmlate() : top(0){}
        void push(const T& i){
            if(top >= ssize) cerr <<"Too many push()es\n";
            else stack[top++]=i;
        }
        T pop(){
            if(top<=0) cerr<<"Too many pop()s\n";
            else return stack[--top];
            exit(1);
        }

        class iterator;
        friend class itertor;
        class iterator{
            StackTepmlate& s;
            int index;
        public:
            iterator(StackTepmlate& st):s(st), index(0){}
            iterator(StackTepmlate& st,bool):s(st),index(s.top){}
            T operator*() const {return s.stack[index];}
            T operator++(){
                if(index >= s.top) cerr<<"iterator moved out of range\n";
                return s.stack[++index];
                exit(1);
            }
            T operator++(int){
                if(index >= s.top) cerr<<"iterator moved out of range\n";
                return s.stack[index++];
                exit(1);
            }
            bool operator==(const iterator& rv) const{
                return index==rv.index;
            }
            bool operator!=(const iterator& rv) const{
                return index!=rv.index;
            }
            friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const iterator& it){
                    return os<<*it; // Line 47 - Intellisense error
            }
        };
        iterator begin(){return iterator(*this);}
        iterator end(){return iterator(*this,true);}
    };
```

IntelliSense: more than one operator "<<" matches these operands :line 47

Further errors, both on line 7:

- Error 1: C2461: 'StackTepmlate' : constructor syntax
  missing formal parameters    7
- Error 2: C2461: 'StackTepmlate' :
  constructor syntax missing formal parameters

Options for missing that I have for T to get worked:

1. Copy ctor
2. Default ctor
3. Operator =
4. Operator ==
5. Operator <<
6. Operator ++
7. Operator --
8. A ctor that recives int
9. A ctor that recives void*

Thank you !!

Comment: You should flag line 47 in the source. I'm not going to count that far!

Comment: I add XXXXX before the line

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to name the class member as well as the class itself?

Comment: Might I suggest a flag that doesn't wreck the code? For example, a comment such as `// <-- Here is line 47`.

Comment: At line 46, are you passing a constant iterator (const iterator) that doesn't change or passing an iterator to constant data (const_iterator)?  Note the underscore between the words.